# What does a Profit Factor of 40 and a ship comprised of 80 Ship Points translate to in a Rogue Trader Game? How would you write such a character?

Tags: character-creation, rogue-trader

I guess I'm just trying to create an OC Rogue Trader with ties to the Mechanicus with this Profit Factor (40) and their main ship having this many Ship Points (80). The Rogue Trader is basically going through all the rule books in the game.

But their connections are to the Mechanicus and their Warrant was given via a reward. Said Rogue Trader is first of his name.

I'm trying to make the Rogue Trader mostly a friend in most endeavours and sometimes an enemy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Fairly wealthy, possibly quite new, with a very powerful ship.

On p. 33 of the Rogue Trader rulebook, we can see that all of the various combinations of Profit Factor and Ship Points add up to 90, as opposed to the 120 of your hypothetical NPC. The maximum Ship Points available to starting PCs is 70, so the ship is more powerful than the most powerful possible starting PC ships; it's probably a Cruiser, Battlecruiser, or Grand Cruiser. Of course, working out the exact build of an NPC ship probably isn't necessary unless it's going to play a recurring role in the campaign (e.g. the PCs captured it, the Rogue Trader has allied with them, or something similar); if it's just showing up for one or two combat scenes before the PCs blow it up, whether it's got Press-Crew Quarters or Voidsman Quarters probably doesn't matter too much, so the most important things for you to pick are its class and its weapon loadout.

The description of a PC group with 50 Ship Points and 40 Profit Factor on that page is "The Rogue Trader dynasty is a fresh, new player on the galactic stage, garnering attention both fair and foul." On p. 270 of Rogue Trader, on the "Profit and Power" table, Profit Factor 40 is listed as "Planetary Noble, Planetary Merchant House, Lesser Rogue Trader, Weak Imperial Governor". To put that into terms we'd be familiar with on Earth, that would basically make you equivalent to Bill Gate, Elon Musk, or the President of the USA - but in an empire of a million worlds, you're still a fairly small fish.